# Reshape 2D to 5D array in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, reshape

I have a set of data that is 2D (M*N). The array covers rectangular grid points and contains various data with respect to time. The data is written as:

```
x1  y1 t1 a b c ...
x2  y1 t1 a b c ...
.   .  .  . . . ...
x50 y1 t1 a b c ...
x1  y2 t1 a b c ...
x2  y2 t1 a b c ...
.   .  .  . . . ...
x50 y2 t1 a b c ...
.   .  .  . . . ...
x50 y40 t1 a b c ...
x1  y1 t2 a b c ...
.
.
.
x50 y40 t30 a b c ...
```

So the array advances x whilst keeping y fixed and writes the data at that point. Y is stepped to the next value, x is advanced, and the data is written. This writing pattern is repeated after the last grid point and time advances. In total, there are 9 cases of such arrays.

I'd like to convert this 2D matrix into a 5D array of such:

```
X , Y , DATA , TIME , CASE
```

So it would be 50 axial grid points, by 40 vertical grid points, by 15 sets of data at each point (x,y,time,a,b,c,etc.), by 30 time stamps, by 9 cases.

I've been playing with the reshape function in Matlab, but it just seems to be impossible to get the array reshaped into the way I would like it to be.

Could anyone provide assistance, please? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems I found the answer. I tried a much smaller array and it turned out that the way to organise the reshape elements was to put it as:

```
B = reshape(A, [X Y TIME DATA CASE])
```

And then the it was a matter of permutation to get the array re-arranged to X, Y, Data, Time, Case.

```
B = reshape(B, [1 2 4 3 5])
```